# How do i get the total number of integers entered into an array returned from a function in C++, as well as the lowest highest and average scores?

Tags: c++, arrays, count, return, pass-by-reference

I am trying to return the number of grades entered into my array by returning it from a function that should also fill the array. Then using that data I would like to pass the array to another function and read out the lowest, highest, and average scores written in to the array. The program I have written is below. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int getGrades(int[], int);
void calcStats(int[], int, int&, int&, double&);

int main()
{
double av;
int count;
const int numGrades = 20;
int grade[numGrades];
int low = grade[0];
int high = grade[0];

count = getGrades(grade, numGrades);

calcStats(grade, count, low, high, av);

cout << "You have entered " << count << " grades." << endl;
cout << "The lowest score was " << low << "." << endl;
cout << "The highest score was " << high << "." << endl;
cout << "The average of all the scores was " << av << "." << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}

int getGrades(int grade[], int size)
{
int gr, count = 0;
cout << "Please enter up to 20 grades and -1 when finished." << endl;
while (cin >> gr && gr != -1)
{
    grade[count] = gr;
    count++;
}
return count;
}
void calcStats(int grade[], int S2, int &low, int &high, double &av)
{
for (int count = 1; count < S2; count++)
    if (grade[count] < low)
    {
        low = grade[count];
    }
for (int count = 1; count < S2; count++)
    if (grade[count] > high)
    {
        high = grade[count];
    }
int total = 0;
for (int count = 0; count < S2; count++)
    total += grade[count];
av = total / S2;
}
```

Sample output as the program reads now is:

```
Please enter up to 20 grades and -1 when finished.
45
45
45 
45
45
-1
You have entered 5 grades.
The highest score was 45.
The lowest score was -85679.
The average of all the scores was 45.
```

The number of grades should in this scenario be 5. The highest, lowest and average should all be 45.

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your question to also include the output of a sample run (e.g., of 5 entries).

Comment: Thanks. I did a simple test run.

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = 0, low = 0, high = 0;

// ...

cout << "You have entered " << count << " grades." << endl;
```

There's nothing in the code that assigns anything to this `count`, that's why you get a value of 0 shown, here.

The number of grades that was entered gets returned from `getGrades()`. This is correct, however `main()` completely ignores the return value from `getGrades()`, and fails to assign it to `count`. Just because `getGrades()` returns the number of grades, it doesn't mean that `count` will be automatically updated.

```
const int numGrades = 20;

calcStats(grade, numGrades, low, high, av);
```

`main()` passes `numGrades` to `calcStats()`, as the number of grades to calculate. It will, obviously, always be 20, and `calcStats()` will always think there are 20 grades to calculate, instead of the actual number of grades that was entered. As such, the calculated results will be complete garbage.

```
low = count + 1;

high = count + 1;
```

`low` and `high` get set to the number of the lowest or highest grade. So, if the 5th entered grade was the lowest grade, say 13, `low` gets set to `5`.

However, the output of main expects to show the value of the actual grade itself, 13, instead of its number, 5.

Furthermore, if the lowest or the highest grade was the very first one entered, `calcGrades()` will fail to set `low` or `high`, at all.

Comment: Okay so I made some changes, but I seem to still be getting an error with the low integer... Not sure why since the read out is the exact same as the high integer besides the less than sign. Any suggestions there?

Comment: `low` and `high` get initialized to the value of `grades[0]`, even before the grades themselves are entered. In other words: "putting the cart before the horse". Johnny Carson's "Carnac, the Magnificent" gag comes to mind, too..

Comment: Thanks. I am still learning the nuances of coding. I appreciate the help. :)